# Compact way of visualizing heat maps of correlated data

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to visualize the correlation of the `Result` column with every other column.

```
   A_B       A_C       B_C         Result
0  0.318182  0.925311  0.860465        91
1 -0.384030  0.991803  0.996344        12
2 -0.818182  0.411765  0.920000        53
3  0.444444  0.978261  0.944444        64
```

`A_B = (A-B)/(A+B)` correspondingly all other values too.

[image]
which works for smaller no. of columns but if I increase the no. of columns then no. of rows in heatmap keeps on stacking up.Is there any compact way to represent it.

Following code will reproduce the output-

```
import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns

data = {'A':[232,243,12,546,67,12,78,11,245],
    'B':[120,546,120,210,56,120,56,89,12],
    'C':[9,1,5,6,7,43,7,12,64],
    'Result':[91,12,53,64,71,436,74,123,641],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C','Result'])

#Responsible for (A-B)/(A+B) ,(A-C)/(A+C) and similarly
colnames = df.columns.tolist()[:-1]
for i,c in enumerate(colnames):
    if i!=len(colnames):
        for k in range(i+1,len(colnames)):
            df[c+'_'+colnames[k]]=(df[c]-df[colnames[k]])/(df[c]+df[colnames[k]])

newdf = df[['A_B','A_C','B_C','Result']].copy()
#Plotting A_B,A_C,B_C by ignoring the output of result of itself
plot = pd.DataFrame(newdf.corr().iloc[:-1,-1])
sns.heatmap(plot,annot=True)
```

A technique which I heard but unable to find any source ,is representing each correlation factor in the mini-recangles like
[image]
So according to it, considering the given map as a matrix of 3*3 and (0,0) starting from left-bottom, A_B will be represented in (1,1)
A_C in (2,1),B_C in (2,2).
But ,I am not getting it how to do it ?

Comment: Any response to my answer below? Does it solve your purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot the correlation of each column against the `Result` column and other columns as well. Below is one way to do so. Providing the x- and y-ticklabels guides you better for comparing the correlations. You can also annotate the correlation values to be displayed on the heat map.

```
cor = newdf.corr()

sns.heatmap(cor, xticklabels=cor.columns.values,
            yticklabels=cor.columns.values, annot=True)
```

[image]